# bindToController in unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm using bindToController in a directive to have the isolated scope directly attached to the controller, like this:

```
app.directive('xx', function () {
  return {
    bindToController: true,
    controller: 'xxCtrl',
    scope: {
      label: '@',
    },
  };
});
```

Then in the controller I have a default in case label is not specified in the HTML:

```
app.controller('xxCtrl', function () {
  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.label = ctrl.label || 'default value';
});
```

How can I instantiate xxCtrl in the Jasmine unit tests so I can test the ctrl.label?

```
describe('buttons.RemoveButtonCtrl', function () {
  var ctrl;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
    // What do I do here to set ctrl.label BEFORE the controller runs?
    ctrl = $controller('xxCtrl');
  }));

  it('should have a label', function () {
    expect(ctrl.label).toBe('foo');
  });
});
```

Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/LS1PDS?p=preview) to test the issue

Comment: I want to be sure the controller doesn't overwrite the label with the default if it's previously specified. If I overwrite it on purpose after the initialization on the beforeEach block or even inside the it block I would be testing the test code itself.

Comment: Looks like the Angular team has added support for this now:http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/5520197d61d7e9d80a9f52db

Comment: The reason you are always getting default values is that Angular hasn't copied the scope values over to the controller yet.  `bindToController` doesn't work synchronously.  The bound controller properties are not guaranteed to be available until after Angular has called the user-defined `$onInit()` method.  That method is where you should put the `ctrl.label = ctrl.label || 'default value';`.  Note that this doesn't fix your problem, but it explains it. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**In Angular 1.3 (see below for 1.4+)**

Digging into the AngularJS source code I found an undocumented third argument to the `$controller` service called `later` (see [$controller source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/controller.js)).

If true, `$controller()` returns a Function with a property `instance` on which you can set properties.
When you're ready to instantiate the controller, call the function and it'll instantiate the controller with the properties available in the constructor.

Your example would work like this:

```
describe('buttons.RemoveButtonCtrl', function () {

  var ctrlFn, ctrl, $scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    ctrlFn = $controller('xxCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
    }, true);
  }));

  it('should have a label', function () {
    ctrlFn.instance.label = 'foo'; // set the value

    // create controller instance
    ctrl = ctrlFn();

    // test
    expect(ctrl.label).toBe('foo');
  });

});
```

Here's an updated Plunker (had to upgrade Angular to make it work, it's 1.3.0-rc.4 now): http://plnkr.co/edit/tnLIyzZHKqPO6Tekd804?p=preview

**Note that it's probably not recommended to use it, to quote from the Angular source code:**

> Instantiate controller later: This machinery is used to create an
>   instance of the object before calling the controller's constructor
>   itself.
>
> This allows properties to be added to the controller before the
>   constructor is invoked. Primarily, this is used for isolate scope
>   bindings in $compile.
>
> This feature is not intended for use by applications, and is thus not
>   documented publicly.

However the lack of a mechanism to test controllers with `bindToController: true` made me use it nevertheless.. maybe the Angular guys should consider making that flag public.

Under the hood it uses a temporary constructor, we could also write it ourselves I guess.
The advantage to your solution is that the constructor isn't invoked twice, which could cause problems if the properties don't have default values as in your example.

**Angular 1.4+ (Update 2015-12-06):**
The Angular team has added direct support for this in [version 1.4.0](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#140-beta6-cookie-liberation-2015-03-17). (See [#9425](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9425))
You can just pass an object to the `$controller` function:

```
describe('buttons.RemoveButtonCtrl', function () {

  var ctrl, $scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    ctrl = $controller('xxCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
    }, {
      label: 'foo'
    });
  }));

  it('should have a label', function () {
    expect(ctrl.label).toBe('foo');
  });
});
```

See also this [blog post](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/5520197d61d7e9d80a9f52db).

Comment: This is much simpler and elegant. It's true that the Angular team has to do something to solve that issue so that these controllers can be tested simply, as the rest of things in angular.

Comment: Looks like they added support now. I did a write up with an example: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/5520197d61d7e9d80a9f52db

Comment: @TGH Yes they added it now. Thanks for the post explaining it.

Comment: BTW the support that @TGH mentioned was added in 1.3.15+.

Answer (score 3):

**Unit Testing BindToController using ES6**

If using ES6,you can import the controller directly and test without using angular mocks.

**Directive:**

```
import xxCtrl from './xxCtrl';

class xxDirective {
  constructor() {
    this.bindToController = true;
    this.controller = xxCtrl;
    this.scope = {
      label: '@'
    }
  }
}

app.directive('xx',  new xxDirective());
```

**Controller:**

```
class xxCtrl {
  constructor() {
    this.label = this.label || 'default value';
  }
}

export default xxCtrl;
```

**Controller Test:**

```
import xxCtrl from '../xxCtrl';

describe('buttons.RemoveButtonCtrl', function () {

  let ctrl;

  beforeEach(() => {
    xxCtrl.prototype.label = 'foo';
    ctrl = new xxCtrl(stubScope);
  });

  it('should have a label', () => {
    expect(ctrl.label).toBe('foo');
  });

});
```

see this for more information:
[Proper unit testing of
Angular JS
applications with ES6 modules](https://blog.ngconsultant.io/proper-testing-of-angular-js-applications-with-es6-modules-8cf31113873f#.y1sif5gho)

Answer (score 1):

In my view, this controller is not meant to be tested in isolation, because it will never work in isolation:

```
app.controller('xxCtrl', function () {
  var ctrl = this;

  // where on earth ctrl.lable comes from???
  ctrl.newLabel = ctrl.label || 'default value';
});
```

It is tightly coupled with the directive relying on receiving its scope properties. It is not re-usable. From looking at this controller, I have to wonder where this variable is coming from. It is no better than a leaky function internally using a variable from outside scope:

```
function Leaky () {

    ... many lines of code here ...

    // if we are here we are too tired to notice the leakyVariable:
    importantData = process(leakyVariable);

    ... mode code here ...

    return unpredictableResult;
}
```

Now I have a leaky function whose behaviour is highly unpredictable based on the variable `leakyVariable` present (or not) in whatever scope the function is called.

Unsurprisingly this function is nightmare to test. Which is actually a good thing, perhaps to force the developer to rewrite the function into something more modular and re-usable. Which is not hard really:

```
function Modular (outsideVariable) {
    ... many lines of code here ...

    // no need to hit our heads against the wall to wonder where the variable comes from:
    importantData = process(outsideVariable);

    ... mode code here ...

    return predictableResult;   
}
```

No leaky issues and really easy to test and re-use. Which to me tells that using the good old `$scope` is a better way:

```
app.controller('xxCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.newLabel = $scope.label || 'default value';
});
```

Simple, short and easy to test. Plus no bulky directive object definition.

The original reasoning behind the `controllerAs` syntax was the leaky scope inherited from the parent. However, directive's isolated scope already solves this problem. Thus I don't see any reason to use the bulkier leaky syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way that is not particulary elegant but works at least (if there's a better option leave a comment).

We set the value that "comes" from the directive, and then we call the controller function again to test whatever it does. I've made a helper "invokeController" to be more DRY.

For example:

```
describe('buttons.RemoveButtonCtrl', function () {

  var ctrl, $scope;
  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('xxCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
    });
  }));

  it('should have a label', function () {
    ctrl.label = 'foo'; // set the value

    // call the controller again with all the injected dependencies
    invokeController(ctrl, {
      $scope: scope,
    });

    // test whatever you want
    expect(ctrl.label).toBe('foo');
  });

});


beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
  window.invokeController = function (ctrl, locals) {
    locals = locals || {};
    $injector.invoke(ctrl.constructor, ctrl, locals);
  };
}));
```

Comment: Seems like Angular has added support for this now. http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/5520197d61d7e9d80a9f52db